# How to programmatic segue from one UIViewController to another without Modal or Push?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit

If one UIViewController is a login screen, and the next one is the app's home screen, what would be the most optimal way to program the transition.

I figure the modal segue class is inappropriate for this situation since ideally the transition to the home screen would be permanent, not temporary. But Push didn't make any sense either, since the login screen isn't a Navigation controller, and that isn't the functionality I'm looking for anyway.

What would be the best way approach this specific case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can present it as modal viewController and then set it as `rootviewController` of `appDelegate`. There are different transition styles:

```
modelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
modelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
modelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
modelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its a login screen (for profiles or custom settings or something) perhaps just a simple view on the same view controller might be enough? Unless you want to create a really complex log in proceadure I dont think you have to create another view controller for this. (just my opinion tho)